# I can't seem to set up flutter, it won't even launch the default dummy app it creates on its own

Tags: flutter

This is the dummy code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Improperly formatted define flag:  FINKI\Kodovi\Android\myApp\myapp\lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The "flutter doctor -v" results

```
C:\Users\Andrej>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale mk-MK)
    • Flutter version 1.17.1 at C:\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision f7a6a7906b (8 days ago), 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 6bc433c6b6
    • Dart version 2.8.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\192.6392135\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\192.6392135
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Andrej\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I've tried updating flutter

I've tried replacing cached_network_image:1.1.3 with cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc in my pubspec.yaml file but there was no such setting in there.

I couldn't find any other solutions for this problem.

Comment: Try opening android folder with Android Studio and try running it as an android application first. If that doesn't work then go into Gradle files and check for outdated libraries which will be indicated by yellow underlines.

Comment: Also check your Flutter sdk path and sdk versions in your build.gradle file.